# One line declare, compare and return in c#

Tags: c#, lambda, functional-programming

I am wondering if is possible to do something like the following code:

```
_ = name.Split(' ') => names.Count() > 1 ?
                new Tuple<string, string>(string.Join(" ", names.Take(names.Count() - 1)), names.Last()) :
                new Tuple<string, string>(name, string.Empty)) ;
```

where `names` is the result of `name.Split(' ')`.

Im not getting how to acces to this result without declaring it in a separated line like:

```
var names = name.Split(' ');
```

This line is what I want to avoid but also I dont want to call every time the Split function.

Anyone know how to resolve this or if it is even possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The real question is why you'd want to write unreadable code. Any execution time you _think_ you save by doing this is wasted by the amount of time needed to read and modify this code at a later moment. Also, is `displayName` supposed to be `name`?

Comment: @CodeCaster It is just for knowing if there is a way or if it is possible. In any case,  I dont find it unreadable. The way to learn is to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
var result = s.Split(' ') is var names && names.Length > 1 ? 
    new Tuple<string, string>(string.Join(" ", names.Take(names.Length - 1)), names.Last()) :
    new Tuple<string, string>(displayName, string.Empty);
```

The `var` pattern is a catch-all for any type or value.

(I turned your calls to `.Count()` into `.Length`, as it's more idiomatic for arrays).

I'd recommend using [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples) instead of `Tuple<T>`:

```
var result = s.Split(' ') is var names && names.Length > 1 ? 
    (string.Join(" ", names.Take(names.Length - 1)), names.Last()) :
    (displayName, string.Empty);
```

Using [C# 8's ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#indices-and-ranges), you can write this as:

```
var result = s.Split(' ') is var names && names.Length > 1 ? 
    (string.Join(" ", names[0..^1]), names[^1]) :
    (displayName, string.Empty);
```

(Note that splitting names using `string.Split` might not be the best way, and splitting them at all is probably a bad idea! See the other excellent answers here).

Comment: Too quick! :)))

Comment: Tank you very much, that was exaclty what I was looking for, and you gave me three variants :)

Comment: `.Trim()` or `RemoveEmptyEntries` would make it EVEN better :)

Answer (score 3):

Not literally answering the question, as canton7's answer using pattern matching does exactly what you want (declaring an inline variable using pattern matching), but this looks like what you actually want to do:

```
var name = "foo bar baz";
var i = name.LastIndexOf(' ');
var firstNames = i > -1 ? name.Substring(0, i) : name;
var lastName = i > -1 ? name.Substring(i + 1, name.Length - i - 1) : "";

var t = new Tuple<string, string>(firstNames, lastName);
```

This implements "the part after the last space, if present, is a last name". Note that this is not true for many last names, which can exist of multiple parts, just as first names.

In other words, you can't reasonably split "Jean Marc De Palma".

Comment: (Purely out of interest, you can also use ranges instead of `.Substring`, if you happen to be using C# 8)

Comment: @canton I've read about those but not used them in practice yet, so I won't be advocating them yet. Am I getting old?

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you change your answer (hence the brackets). C#'s adding new syntax at such a rate now that I think we're all starting to feel a little old!

Comment: Thank you @CodeCaster for you answer :). This looks nice also. Don't feel old, I am very young and also need to follow all the fast changes!

Comment: @tymtam [yeah I know](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Multipart lastnames (family name affix) are very common where I come from, "DeVries" and "de Vries" are two different names, to be stored and sorted differently.

Answer (score 2):

@canton7's answer is a beauty, but this algorithm doesn't work for John von Neumann and even for your own name!

```
var name = "Jesús Narváez Tamés";
var displayName = "TODO";


var fl = name.Split(' ') is var names && names.Count() > 1 
            ? (string.Join(" ", names.Take(names.Count() - 1)), names.Last())
            : (displayName, string.Empty);

Console.WriteLine($"First: {fl.Item1}");
Console.WriteLine($"Last: {fl.Item2}");
```

```
First: Jesús Narváez
Last: Tamés
```

Names and [surnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surname) are versatile. Don't split it this way.

Comment: Yes, you're aboslutely right! Thats one problem im having too. For example, in Spanish your name can be "Alonso Fernando" and lastname "Alonso" again. Or you name can just be "Fernando" and lastname "Alonso". I have sincerely no idea how difeer them on code.