# Left side object is not null operator in one line

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that looks up an item that may or may not exist, using `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

var items = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar" }
};

var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1);
if (item != null)
{
     item.Bar = "Baz";
}
```

Is there a way to make a oneliner out of those last four lines, something like this?

```
items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1)?.Bar = "Baz";
```

This gives a compiler error:

> CS9030: The left-hand side of an assignment cannot contain a null propagating operator

Comment: Short answer: no.

Comment: Well, "one liner" is kind of a relative concept to begin with.  This is one line of text: `var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1); if(item != null) item.Count = 1;`  The point being that if the count of carriage returns is the primary focus of the code then that's generally a sign of other problems.

Comment: @DhavalR `FirstOrDefault` returns `T`, which can definately have a property named `Count`

Comment: I think `Count` can't be assigned a value.

Comment: @DhavalR `item` is a class of any type. Therefor, it can have a property called `Count`. That's different to a linq-function count or the count-property of a `List`.

Comment: @Dhaval yes, it can be. `items` is a collection of a type that has a `Count` property; OP could have named it `Foo` for clarity. It's not the `Count` property of the collection.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for by chance?  `int count = (items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1) != null) ? 1 : 0; `'

Comment: I have modified the OP's code so all the confusion about `Count` disappears.

Comment: @DhavalR `item` is not a thing yet. OP doesn't know if item will be an actual item or `null`. So that wouldn't work

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you, this is better

Comment: @rory.ap nope, I want to assign value to item I'm trying to find if that item is not null

Comment: @Kasta I think your `if` statement is the most clear. There is an option for some sort of extension method or something but it either be non-reusable like Chriz's answer or use reflection etc. and it would get less stable and less readable.

Comment: This is one instance where the fact that C# hides the fact that a property is a function invocation is annoying (since if the function could be invoked directly the problem would be much easier).

Comment: A one liner: `foreach (var item in items) if (item.Id == 1){ item.Bar = "buz"; break; }` ;-)

Comment: @Magnus Consider changing the `if` to a `Where` and `Take` (to avoid the need for `break`).

Comment: A "one-liner" from a slight re-org of your already existing code: if (items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1) is var item && item != null) item.Bar = "Baz";

Answer (score 4):

You could use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is) to shorten it:

```
if (items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1) is Foo f)
{
    f.Bar = "Qux";
}
```

Because that negates to `false` when `FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`.

Somewhat related to [One line declare, compare and return in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58625038/one-line-declare-compare-and-return-in-c-sharp/58625260?noredirect=1#comment103558733_58625260).

Comment: Thank you, this is probably best answer. At least one less line.

Comment: Hadn't thought about that! Very nice.

Comment: The downside of this code is that if `items` changes type the code will still compile, but change behaviour (as compared to the original code).

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option.

```
items.Where(i => i.Id == 1).Take(1).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Bar = "Baz" );
```

---

```
var items = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar" },
    new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar again!" }
};

items.Where(i => i.Id == 1).Take(1).ToList().ForEach(f => f.Bar = "Baz" );

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items.Select(i => i.Bar)));
```

```
Baz, Bar again!
```

Comment: This is the only one-line-solution without additional extention methods or anything else which fulfills all criteria. Also usable on every type of item and property.

Comment: And what if there is no matching item Foo with Id == 1? Will it run without exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can this simplay encapsulate it into a function and then use it as a one-liner.

```
private static void SetCountToOneIfExists(this IEnumerable<Foo> items, int id)
{
    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
    if(item != null)
       item.Bar = 1;
}

items.SetCountToOneIfExists(1);
```

In my example I've used an extension method, you can use a normal one (`private void SetCountToOneIfExists(IEnumerable<Foo> items, int Id)`) as well.

Whether one should throw an exception if the item doesn't exist or how to handle that is another story.

Comment: Yes, but now you have even more lines to do the same, and a non-reusable extension method.

Comment: @CodeCaster We dont know if it's not reusable for OP or even why OP wants to shorten this. This is a solution to make his call on the list of objects itself shorter.

Comment: @Chrᴉz as CodeCaster said I dont need it for this solution, I just want to know if is it possible with something I don't know/didnt see yet

Comment: @Chrᴉz I changed your code so the parameter makes sense ;) (you just forgot no worries). Also you could make this a little bit more re-usable by making it `SetCountToXIfExists` and have X be a parameter so its not limited to setting to 1.

Comment: @EpicKip ty for fixing a bug. I will not change the fixed value of 1 here as the function has to be adjusted anyway for anyone to use it. They can then add another parameter or another type as well. I was also thinking about a generic solution, but that'd be too much here.

Answer (score 0):

You could if you modify `Foo`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    internal string SetBar(string v) => Bar = v;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<Foo>{ new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar" } };

    items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1)?.SetBar("Baz");   
}
```

---

## set_Bar

For the record, the compiler will reject an attempt to call set_Bar` directly

```
items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == 1)?.set_Bar("Baz");
// 'Program.Foo.Bar.set': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor (CS0571)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1) ?? new Foo()).Bar = "Baz";
```

You could even create an extension, which I believe should be somewhat reusable:

```
public static T FirstOrNew<T>(this IEnumerable<T> lst, Func<T, bool> predicate) 
    => Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(lst, predicate) ?? default;
```

Then your usage would be:

```
items.FirstOrNew(x => x.Id == 1).Bar = "Baz";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safer version of the pattern matching solution. This version is resistant to changing the type `items` holds. I'd call it the no-casting solution.

```
if( items.Where(i => i.Id == 1).Take(1) is var x && x.Any()) { x.First().Bar = "Baz"; }
```

---

```
var items = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar" },
    new Foo { Id = 1, Bar = "Bar again!" }
};

if( items.Where(i => i.Id == 1).Take(1) is var x && x.Any()) { x.First().Bar = "Baz"; }

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items.Select(i => i.Bar)));

//Not found? No problem (i.e. no exception)
if( items.Where(i => i.Id == 2).Take(1) is var x2 && x2.Any()) { x2.First().Bar = "Baz2"; }
```

Output

```
Baz, Bar again!
```

Comment: Yes, but, yes, but, no. This isn't Code Golf. :P

Comment: Isn't it? I'm going to bed then! ;)

Answer (score 0):

My *personal* preference would be to keep the null check, as it's clear and easy to understand.

However, if your preference is to reduce the check and assignment down to a one-liner, you could create a generic extension method:

```
 public static class NullExtensions
 {
     public static void UpdateIfNotNull<T>(this T item, Action<T> update)
         where T : class
     {
         if (item != null)
         {
             update(item);
         }
     }
 }
```

And use it as follows:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
...

var foo = new Foo();

//One-liner
foo.UpdateIfNotNull(f => f.Bar = 2);
```